# Get month and Date from Year in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the date and month from Year entered by user.

Query I have used is:

```
SELECT trans_date FROM transactions WHERE (SUBSTR(trans_date,4,4) = 'June' AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(trans_date,9,4)) = 2010);
```

This is not working but if I do the same with DUAL table it works.

```
SELECT SUBSTR('22-June-2018', 4, 4) FROM DUAL;
```

What is the problem with it ?

Comment: What's the datatype of `trans_date`?

Comment: What are example values of `trans_date`?

Comment: May because of 2010 vs 2018?

Comment: If it is a string, (a) it shouldn't be, and (b) you'd need to find the start of the year more cleverly than that as month name lengths vary. I imagine you're replying on implicit conversion from date to string anyway though, in which case use Gordon's approach. Maybe your client is formatting the date values separately from your NLS settings, which could confuse things for you too; but it's still not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered something like `to_char()`?

```
SELECT trans_date
FROM transactions
WHERE TO_CHAR(trans_date, 'YYYY-MM') = '2010-06';
```

Or better yet, proper date comparisons:

```
WHERE trans_date >= DATE '2010-06-01' AND
      trans_date < DATE '2010-07-01'
```

This has the advantage that the query can use an index on `trans_date`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(trans_date,'DD-Month-YYYY'),'DD') day,
       to_char(to_date(trans_date,'DD-Month-YYYY'),'Month') month
FROM transactions
WHERE to_char(to_date(trans_date,'DD-Month-YYYY'),'Month') = 'June' 
AND to_char(to_date(trans_date,'DD-Month-YYYY'),'YYYY') = '2010');
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem with it ?

`SUBSTR( string_value, start, length )` takes a string data type as the 1st argument. `'22-June-2018'` is not a `DATE` data type - it is a string data type (that just happens to contain characters that we recognise as a date); so using `SUBSTR( '22-June-2018', 4, 4 )` works as expected.

`trans_date` is a `DATE` data type and not a string data type.

```
SUBSTR( trans_date, 4, 4 )
```

Involves an implicit conversion from a date to a string; so is effectively doing:

```
SUBSTR( TO_CHAR( trans_date ), 4, 4 )
```

Since, `TO_CHAR( date_value, format_model )` needs to know how to format the `DATE` to a string, if you do not provide a second argument then it will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and the expression is effectively:

```
SUBSTR(
  TO_CHAR(
    trans_date
    ( SELECT value FROM nls_session_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  4,
  4
)
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter does not match `DD-Month-YYYY` (or something equivalent where the 4-7th characters are month (which it would only be for 4-character month names) and 9th-12th characters are year (again, this would only be true for months with 4-character names) then your query will not work.

> I am trying to get the date and month from Year entered by user.

Use `EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT trans_date
FROM   transactions
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH FROM trans_date ) = 6
AND    EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM trans_date ) = 2010
```

Use `TO_CHAR( date_value, format_model )`:

```
SELECT trans_date
FROM   transactions
WHERE  TO_CHAR( trans_date, 'Month' ) = 'June'
AND    TO_CHAR( trans_date, 'year'  ) = '2010'
```

Use date literals:

```
SELECT trans_date
FROM   transactions
WHERE  trans_date >= DATE '2010-06-01'
AND    trans_date < ADD_MONTHS( DATE '2010-06-01', 1 );
```

Use `TRUNC( date_value, 'MM' )`:

```
SELECT trans_date
FROM   transactions
WHERE  TRUNC( trans_date, 'MM' ) = DATE '2010-06-01';
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use like

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(date_column_name,'MM-YYYY')='06-2010'
```